# ax.hist not outputting the same as np.histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but I'm not able to generate a histogram using `ax.hist`. When I attempt to use `ax.hist` to plot a `numpy.nd.array` I'm presented with a blank graph. When investigating the returned list and bins, the list are all 0 which shouldn't be the case. When I output the list of values and bins using `numpy.histogram()` I'm presented with the correct values and am able to plot what I need using `ax.bar()`. Additionally, I've also checked using `skimage.expose.histogram` which returns the same as `numpy.histogram()`

for completeness, I'm loading the following image with `skimage.io` and attempting the plot the histograms showing the colour intensity of each channel. The code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np    
import skimage
from skimage import io, color

img = io.imread(MY_IMAGE_PATH)
print(type(img)) # numpy.nd.array
print(img.shape) # (256, 256, 4)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
grid_size = (1, 1)

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(grid_size, (0, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
# hist, bins = skimage.exposure.histogram(img[:, :, 0])
# ax1.bar(bins, hist, width=1, color="red")
n, bins, _ = ax1.hist(img[:, :, 0].ravel(), bins=256, range=(0.0, 1.0), color="white") # Red channel
ax.set_facecolor((44/255, 53/255, 57/255)) # dark gray background
values, np_bins = np.histogram(img[:, :, 0].ravel()
```

the image that I'm loading: [image]

I have a work around but I would like to know if the problem is with my code or if this is indeed a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Plotting white bars on a white background will make them invisible. Use some other color, e.g. `color="red"`.
2. Setting the range of values to be (0,1) makes no sense if the values to histogram are between 0 and 255. Rather use `range=(0, 255)`.

Comment: 1. Sorry, I forgot to include `ax.set_facecolor((44/255, 53/255, 57/255))` which is a dark background.
2. The `range` paramater fixed it.